# Steering Rack Clicking Noise

Tags: steering

My steering wheel on a Mitsubishi Outlander MY2011 is making a clicking noise that seems to come from right tyre (on a RHD).

All tie rods and bushes have just been replaced, as was the CV Boot. The suspension was also checked.

Here's a video of the noise when driving on an all weather road, while not holding the steering so it's playing from side to side.

The video was shot at night, so it's dark. Other than the spring noise, the louder sound is the steering. https://photos.app.goo.gl/uoKZbRdgnubr418M9

Comment: I seriously cannot tell what's going on from the video. What are you doing to cause the noise? Are you turning the wheel back and forth? Does the noise happen at the same point in the revolution of the steering wheel (if that's what you're doing)? Please, elaborate.

Comment: At this point I'm not touching the wheel - it's hands free. The car is moving forward on acceleration, the noise is from the steering as the right tyre goes over the rough surface. Also happens when I go over rumble strips.

Comment: If the steering wheel is straight and not being moved while the noise is occuring, it's not the steering rack making the noise. The only time the steering rack will directly make noise is when it's being manipulated ... unless it's loose on the car itself (not mounted securely). Other than that, I'd be looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a back and forth with my maintenance guy as I suspect worn steering bushings from corrugations, while he's convinced it's an aging rack and changing the bushes won't resolve much. Will suggest we reopen and check where the rack connects with different points at the bottom.

Comment: Cv boot replacement won't stop a worn cv joint from clicking.. if deciding whether it's bushes or rack, replace the quicker/easier/cheaper component first

Comment: The rack is a bit pricey and the expert was of the opinion to leave it till rack absolutely needs replacing. After further research, he is of the opinion that glue holding 2 steering columns came loose in heavy corrugation and 40 degree (104 F) weather and that's what's causing the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually took apart the rack, and the gear was worn. It had free play and also appears the bearing underneath was worn too. Got a salvage sterring gear and rack and the noise is gone.

However, my repair guy was of the opinion that the steering gear was usable for more than 20,000 kilometres and even more. It's worth changing when steering becomes too difficult.

Apparently later model Subarus with electric steering are even worse since they fail faster under rough roads and are at least more than 3 times the cost of hydraulic ones. So the owners just live with the noise.